Raspberry pi camera module photos from script too low resolution
Please forgive me as I am not a programmer, I cannot code and I have never learned to code. However, I need some code to take a photo with a raspberry pi camera module V2 every x minutes and upload it to an ftp server. This way I can check on a chemical reaction that runs overnight in a lab (I'm a chemist). I already spent 8 hours trying to get the #(@ working but all I get are syntax errors or blinking cursors.
I can make jpg's from command line, but they are only 20kb and 800x600. I need them 3280 * 2464 (the native camera resolution). I think I have a command for that in my code, but it doesn't work.
How do I fix this? This is my code so far:
from picamera2 import Picamera2, Preview
from datetime import datetime
import time
from ftplib import FTP
picam2 = Picamera2()
camera_config = picam2.create_preview_configuration()
picam2.configure(camera_config)

ftp = FTP('server')
ftp.login('user','pass')

pics_taken = 0
max_pics = 1

while pics_taken <= max_pics:
        picam2.start()
        time.sleep(2)
        picam2.resolution = (3280, 2464)
        current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
        filename = "base" + current_datetime + ".jpg"
        picam2.capture_file(filename)
        pics_taken += 1
        time.sleep(3)


        file = open(filename,'rb')                  # file to send
        ftp.retrlines('LIST')
        file.close()                                    # close file and FTP
 ftp.quit()

I tried to add picam2.resolution command, but it does not help.
